# Max mobile app size before wifi is required to download/install

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry

I am looking into making a cross platform mobile application.  I know that the apple store won't allow you to download and install an app that is over 50MB.  Do the google or blackberry app stores have a similar restriction. I can't find anything that doesn't say they don't, but I don't want to assume.

Comment: That is very similar.  I am looking for blackberry and Android, and something a little less dated, but I certainly have more search terms to try.

Comment: @Raghunandan, and others who voted to close:  This question is about a cross-platform app that's also deployed to Blackberries.  The duplicate does **not** address this.  Please read carefully before voting to close.  Thanks.

Comment: it's 100 MB for iOS now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### BlackBerry

If you're referring to the legacy BlackBerry Java platform, [the maximum size of an app is actually only *about* 14 MB](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-7-or-earlier-smartphone/ta-p/1300209).

If you're referring to the new BlackBerry OS's, [see this document](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-10-or-BlackBerry-PlayBook-OS/ta-p/1026013):

> BlackBerry 10 and BlackBerry PlayBook OS version 1.0.6 and later
> supports applications (BAR files) up to 2 GB in size.
>
> BlackBerry PlayBook OS version 1.0.5 and earlier supports applications
> (BAR files) up to 300 MB in size.

### Android

On Android, the size [is for all intents and purposes unlimited (50MB + 2GB + 2GB)](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html), if you use [expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).  Of course, if you're on a 3G connection, it's going to be quite slow to download apps that are larger than the old 50MB hard maximum, and may incur significant costs for your users with data limited plans.

### iOS

For completeness, [here's the Apple link stating that the current Over-the-Air download limit is 50MB](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/18_BestPractices/BestPractices.html), as you said.

---

**Note:** the Google/BlackBerry sizes are limits that do not depend on the download connection type (e.g. carrier network vs. Wi-Fi).  Your users may have additional limits imposed by their carriers, but that's impossible to comment on without knowing which carriers you're targeting.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022-Sep-19:

---

**Android - 150MB (AAB) or 100MB (APK)**

If you use the newer Android App Bundle format (AAB) for packaging then the limit is 150MB for cellular downloads (expandable through Play Asset Delivery).

If you use the older Android Package format (APK) then the limit is 100MB for cellular downloads (expandable through OBB expansion packs).

Resources:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery
- https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files

---

**iOS - 200MB (soft limit - user preference)**

Previously, it was 100MB, then 150MB in 2017, and finally in 2019 with iOS 13 it is now a soft-limit of 200MB defined in settings.

Today the user can choose how downloads over cellular behave:

- "Always Allow"
- "Ask if Over 200 MB"
- "Always Ask"

Resources:

- https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09192017b
- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/manage-purchases-subscriptions-and-settings-iph3dfd91de/13.0/ios/13.0

Comment: This should be the right answer, thanks for the effort and the links!